# How can I parse a JSON string to .Net object using Json.Net?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, json.net

The string I want to parse:

```
[
    {
    id: "new01"
    name: "abc news"
    icon: ""
    channels: [
    {
    id: 1001
    name: "News"
    url: "http://example.com/index.rss"
    sortKey: "A"
    sourceId: "1"
    },
    {
    id: 1002
    name: "abc"
    url: "http://example.com/android.rss"
    sortKey: "A"
    sourceId: "2"
    } ]
    },
{
    id: "new02"
    name: "abc news2"
    icon: ""
    channels: [
    {
    id: 1001
    name: "News"
    url: "http://example.com/index.rss"
    sortKey: "A"
    sourceId: "1"
    },
    {
    id: 1002
    name: "abc"
    url: "http://example.com/android.rss"
    sortKey: "A"
    sourceId: "2"
    } ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I had try, read all document but unsuccessfull:D

Comment: To an object you created or to a JsonObject?

Answer (score 5):

Your JSON isn't actually JSON - you need commas after the fields:

```
[
    {
    id: "new01",
    name: "abc news",
    icon: "",
    channels: [
    {
    id: 1001,
       ....
```

Assuming you've done that and that you are using [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx), then you'll need classes to represent each of the elements - the main elements in the main array, and the child "Channel" elements.

Something like:

```
    public class Channel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SortKey { get; set; }
        public string SourceId { get; set; }            
    }

    public class MainItem
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public List<Channel> Channels { get; set; }
    }
```

Because there is a mismatch between the C# member naming conventions and the JSON names, you'll need to decorate each member with a mapping to tell the JSON parser what the json fields are called:

```
    public class Channel
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("sortkey")]
        public string SortKey { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("sourceid")]
        public string SourceId { get; set; }            
    }

    public class MainItem
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("icon")]
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("channels")]
        public List<Channel> Channels { get; set; }
    }
```

Once you've done this, you can parse a string containing your JSON like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MainItem>>(inputString);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try your way and notify result. Thanks Damian.

Answer (score 0):

yup, it's  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json string)

try using JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object)  to create the JSON.